# Bootstrap v5 wp-bootstrap-navwalker dropdown navbar not work

Tags: javascript, wordpress, function, navbar, bootstrap-5

I use Bootstrap v5 and [wp-bootstrap-navwalker][1] 
in function.php

```
<?php
  require_once('class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php');
  function main_menu(){
    wp_nav_menu(array(
      'theme_location'    => 'main-menu',
      'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
      'depth'             => 2,
      'container'         => 'div',
      'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
      'container_id'      => 'navbarSupportedContent',
      'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
      'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
    ));
  }
?>
```

in header.php

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <?php main_menu() ?>
  </div>
</nav>
```

the dropdown menu not work 
[1]: https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Comment: `Questions which are too broad, unclear, incomplete or primarily opinion-based` may be **[closed by the community](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)** until they are improved.

Comment: What doesn't work?  On hover open the sub-menu?  On click open the sub-menu?  There's no menu at all?  Please provide more details.

Comment: @HowardE the dropdown menu does not work in bootstrap 5 the menu 
`
function register_all_menu() {
    register_nav_menus(array(
      'top_menu' => 'القائمة العلوية',
      'main-menu' => 'القائمة الرئيسية',
      'footer-menu' => 'القائمة السفلية',
    ));
  }
`
I also check this article but not work too
[https://github.com/AlexWebLab/bootstrap-5-wordpress-navbar-walker]

Comment: you can use this [navwalker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/blob/master/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php)
and in line 214 change for this:
`if ( $this->has_children && 0 === $depth ) {
$atts['href']            = '#';
$atts['data-bs-toggle']      = 'dropdown';
$atts['aria-haspopup'] = 'true';
$atts['aria-expanded']  = 'false';
$atts['class']           = 'dropdown-toggle nav-link';
$atts['id']              = 'navbarDropdown';
}`

Comment: Changing to ```$atts['data-bs-toggle']``` worked for me!

Comment: In my case I just put my id from here `data-bs-target="#navbarNav"` to `'container_id'`

Answer (score 10):

#### Bootstrap 5.0.0 [ 2021 ]

Tested and Working ✔

This function below will update `data-toggle` to `data-bs-toggle`.

```php
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'bootstrap5_dropdown_fix' );
function bootstrap5_dropdown_fix( $atts ) {
     if ( array_key_exists( 'data-toggle', $atts ) ) {
         unset( $atts['data-toggle'] );
         $atts['data-bs-toggle'] = 'dropdown';
     }
     return $atts;
}
```

> Source: https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/issues/499

#### Fixing the Hamburger icon dropdown

OP already using the new navbar elements. But if any of you using the old one and updated only the functions from above, then follow the steps below.

In responsive the Hamburger icon will not work if you are using the old classes. You also have to update your from `data-toggle` to `data-bs-toggle`

```html
<button ... data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" ...>
   <!--span-->
</button>
```